# Prevent page from reloading when button is click

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, console, code-behind

I wanna display a label text but i notice that the page reloads once i click the button. Is there any way i could prevent this?

```
<asp:Button ID="openSide" runat="server" class="fa fa-bars" OnClientClick="writeLabel"></asp:Button>
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="label1"></asp:Label>
```

```
Protected Sub openSidebar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        label1.Text="test"
End Sub
```

and sometimes i get these errors. what does it mean?

the right one is from a different part but it seems as if it couldn't detect the codebehind sub and the right one is for this label problem.

[Errors here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5trb.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think most are missing this question.

The poster states that their code works just fine, but the problem is that clicking on the button cases a page post back. The goal then is how to NOT have a page post back, but achieve the SAME goal.

Well, before I give two solutions, the first question:

The page post back might not be all that bad. asp.net webforms are VERY nice in that you get a desktop like experience (say like ms-access or even VB applications for the desktop). That means you have that forms designer, and you can drop in a text box, drop in a button. Double click on that button and now you get to write simple and clean vb code. you are off to the races writing code. This is oh so easy - child's play, and that's why asp.net forms work this way (they were designed with desktop people in mind). Today, with MVC? You don't even have a forms designer anymore - talk about smelly monkey balls for a development system! - that's right NO visual forms designer.  And people wonder why web development is so costly right now???

Ok,

So, in a matter of 1 minute, without web experience, you have a text box, a button, and are now running code. And you using the simple and easy basic programming language - something we all learned on those computers we had in grade school.

So, the up-side of the so called post back?

The code is REALLY REALLY easy to write. So, in a lot of cases, so what if you do have a post back? It not really the end of the world. If the trade off is spending 3 days to learn some code JUST to avoid this? Well then that price is too high (at least it is if you value your time).

As you learn things and get better? Then yes, you can have less and less post-backs, and improve the user experience. But that reduced use of post-backs comes at a VERY high cost. That high cost is an increased learning curve, and you having to write MORE code, and code that not dead super simple like you have done.

So my first (less then ideal) answer is:

The post back in some cases is not all that bad. The controls etc. on that form in most cases will SURVIVE the round trip (round trip is a concept in which you click on that button, the web page travels up to the server, your code behind runs, maybe modifies controls, and then the page travels back down to the browser. So just keep in mind that as you type and tab around and enter things into that webform, the server does NOTHING and does not even know you did anything until that all important post-back).

The next approach, and this will IS VERY much preferred - especially when new to this.
This trick involves what we call a update panel.  This allows "parts" of the page to run and operate WITHOUT that post back. And what is REALLY nice is you don't have to learn JavaScript, or write any browser side code.

So, if you have some search screen, and want to display the results in a grid (say a gridview control), then you can put all of that into the up-date panel. As a result, when you click on a button and run code behind? The whole page is NOT posted back, and you not even see the browser little "spinny" thing go. This is one of my FAVORATE features of asp.net web forms. You can build and wire up complex forms, and do so whiteout HUGE amounts of learning about JavaScript, ajax calls etc. An amazing feature.

Keep in mind a few things about up-date panels:

```
The web page on-load event DOES FIRE each time.
The post-back is what we call a partial post back.
Only bits and parts in that panel can be updated by code behind.
```

Ok, so lets take your code and move it into a update panel.

So, we drag a text box onto the form.
We drag a button onto the form.

We have this:

[image]

Now, double click on the button on the above, and we can do this:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    TextBox1.Text = "Hello world"

End Sub
```

So, we typed in that ONE line of simple basic code.

Ok, now this works, but it has a post back.

So, now, lets get rid of the full post back:

The steps are:

Just under your "form" tag,

```
drag + drop script manager.
drag + drop in a update panel.
```

These two:

[image]
Hit enter in the markup to break it up like this:

We now have this:

In editor, click inbetween the update panel, tags, tap enter key.
Now, inside the panel tags, start typing content" (let intel-sense finish), and whack enter.

Cut + re-paste the bottom two tages (update and contente) part  to surround your two controls.

Move the closing Updatepanel and content (cut) to BELOW your existing code like this:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
       <ContentTemplate>
       <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" Width="110px" />
       </div>

       </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```

You are now done. (so move (surround) what we had inside of contentTemplate and update paneal). It takes about 10 seconds tops to do this once you get the hang of drag + drop and intel-sense.
Now try running this code. Note how we do NOT see a browser post back!

Behind the scenes, a whole bunch of ajax and JavaScript is wired up for you - but you don't care.

ONLY things inside that update panel will update, and you don't get a full page post back. (this means ALL OTHER controls and other things will not be touched, and thus not get messed up by the post back).

Now, to be fair, for just one button and one text box, it hard to make the case for all that work to prevent a page post back. But, if that button + text box was on a complex page and a full post-back would blow up everything else on that page (and a post back often will)

last option: - write browser side code.

So, we can eliminate the post back by using (and writing) browser side code. Now while this is more difficult, it also the MOST exciting part of web development. And the reason is that you can have code run 100% browser side. This not only means no post back but ZERO interaction with the server will occur. The result is desktop speed of interaction. There is no delay, and you note that this option responds very fast - without delay. and the reason is NOT round trip to the server will occur.

The only down side is you have to start learning and using JavaScript (js). I don't mind the language, but without a nice syntax and compiler? Well you often have to run the code to find errors, and it sucks huge that no real decent compile time syntax checking occurs.

So, for this last option?

lets cut out the update panel and content tags (just delete them, and now do this:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
       <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" Width="110px" 
            OnClientClick="myhello();return false"/>
       </div>
       <script>
          function myhello() {
               tBox = document.getElementById('<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>');
               tBox.value = 'Hello world';
           }
       </script>
</form>
```

Note VERY carefully - in the onClientClick we have a return = false. This means that the vb code behind will NOT run or be called. (and we can have both js code, and the code behind run if we remove the return=false. So at this point, you could delete (remove) the server side code-behind that sets the text box.

And code to set a label (as opposed to a text box) is this:

```
tLbl = document.getElementById('<%= Label1.ClientID %>');
tLbl.innerText = 'Hello world';
```

So for a text box, you use ".value"

For a label, you use ".innerText"

You note again that you don't see or feel a post back (like the up-date panel), but you find that the this last example responds very fast - all without any server side code. it all runs 100% browser side.